# Web mapping application with time slider and raster data

Tags: raster, web-mapping, timeslider

I need to create a web mapping application that can show raster layer of historical maps with a time slider.

Basically, something like this: http://goo.gl/GYHOX

I have different maps of different years of the same are, that can be showed on a time series and moving on with a time slider. The interface can be simple, the important thing is the time slider.

I have programming experience only in HTML/CSS, little of PHP.

Any suggestions of which tools to use? I had a look at TileMill but the problem is the time-slider that I have no clue on how to build it.

Thanks in advance for who will help me.

Comment: timemap with examples is timeline library https://code.google.com/p/timemap/ just need a play/loop function to animate the sequences

Comment: This may be a related Q&A: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18760/web-mapping-software-for-a-huge-raster-time-series

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried inspecting the [page's source](http://map.swisstopo.admin.ch/) (e.g. with Firefox's developer tools)? Looks like it's using [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) and [GeoExt](http://geoext.org/). The time slider appears to be a custom development (check out the functions in the `GeoAdmin` namespace in the `app.js` source -- you will probably want to use something like [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to make it readable).